# javascript функция игнорирует условие в if

Tags: javascript, java

```
/*

 - Javascript  customRecord represents a row from the custom input
   data.   
 - dbRecord represents the corresponding data from DataBase.  
 - dbRecord will be null if there is no corresponding record in
   DataBase.   
 - return true if this rule should be applied to this custom
   record.

*/

function applyRule(customRecord, dbRecord){
    if (dbRecord.containsRole("ReportAdmin")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Есть некая js консоль на тестируемом сервисе с описанием объектов и куском кода в котором необходимо менять условие в зависимости от требований.
В текущем необходимо применять правило для определенной роли, и не применять во всех остальных случаях. НО условие описанное в if полностью игнорируется - и функция всегда возвраoает false. Из копаний в индусовском коде пока удалось узнать только то, что contaisRole это java метод. Как он здесь применяется пока загадка. В логах никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: Так не бывает. Если функция false - значит, такой роли нет. Или вы привели не тот код, который реально выполняется.

Comment: Браузеры уже год не поддерживают джаву.

Answer (score 0):

javascript не может просто так игнорировать

```
function applyRule(customRecord, dbRecord) {
    return !!dbRecord.containsRole('ReportAdmin')
}
```

Пробуйте вернуть значение, если возвращается всегда false, значит функция `dbRecord.containsRole('ReportAdmin')` возвращает отрицательное значение, иначе быть не может.

**P.S!**
Возможно, в вашем случае функция containsRole возвращает позицию найденной строки внутри исходной. Т.е. возвращает 0, например. В данном случае это будет результат положительный, отрицательным — -1. Соответственно, при успешно найденной строке функция будет возвращать false. Попробуйте так:

```
function applyRule(customRecord, dbRecord) {
    return dbRecord.containsRole('ReportAdmin') > -1
}
```

А лучше, дебажьте функцию и смотрите что она возвращает в разных случаях.